# change category and subcategory url separator hyphen

Tags: url

i want change category and subcategory URL separator like(Example site:http://www.flyingmachine.co.in/)

example:
Mobile/brand/samsung

want change to
Mobile-brand-samsung

Comment: have you tried something

Comment: i have tried url management in admin that's static method, i want change dynamically for all categories and subcategories